# Loading an HTML page in a modal

Tags: jquery, html, simplemodal, nivo-slider

I'm using simpleModal to display a picture slider on my website. The person would hit a button and the modal would pop up with the picture slider inside it. The problem is that I have another picture slider lower on the page. The picture slider only works once on a page. So if I put in the modal, the picture slider below it stops working. So, I made an HTML document that has just the picture slider on the page. How would I go about loading that HTML document inside the Modal window??

I'm using **[simpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)** for the modal
I'm using **[nivo-slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)** for the picture slider

Look on **[this](http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/ultimate.html)** page for the picture slider. <-- That is the page that the modal with the slider in it will go in.
**[This](http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/LandscapeSlider.html)** is the page I want to load inside the modal.

Look **[here](http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/Test.html)** for an example of the slider inside the modal.

So yeah, the reason I'm doing all this is because nivo-slider won't work twice on one page. So basically I'm looking for a workaround and this is what I thought of, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why won't it work twice on one page? If that's true, it seems like a crappy plugin. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a shitty fix, but just copy the js for nivo and rename the function. then apply that version of the slider to your modal.

Comment: nivo isn't a function with one name that is called, it uses different function on different html objects when they are given a specific classname. I would have to go through all nivo's code to rename all the classes, and then change all the classes in my HTMl, and then make a CSS section to match those classes. That is a lot of work to do =S I'll do it if I have to though, I know how.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that.  Can you elaborate on why it doesn't work twice on one page?  I was able to make 2 picture sliders using firebug on the nivo website.

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work twice on one page, I tried it on my website listed above and no matter what order I put them in, the second one wouldn't work.

Comment: I might have to remove everything to do with nivo and simplemodal from my page and restart form scratch

Comment: It should work.  You should post the code for that and see if you can get answers for why it won't.  Probably better than the workaround you are trying to implement.

Comment: Okay, I'll start working on it and post back here in a little while

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. My problem was that I needed the different sliders with different sizes. It wasn't as hard as I thought it would be. I just had to give them different ID's and then call them seperately at the bottom and give them id-specific CSS properties in the CSS file. Now to see if I can get one of them to work in a modal window

Comment: I had to accept that answer since there was no other one to accept. By the way, I got it to work. except the nivo-slider inside the modal breaks if you close the modal and then re-open it

Comment: yeah, its a dirty fix man, i don't "recommend" it, but i know how it is. you wanna post link to the modal disappearing? we can fiddle with it.